# Windows Phone - Launch website on open

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to load a website on opening an app, but when I hit build I get 7 errors. Can someone help me with this? Current code is:

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;

namespace Microsoft.Phone.Tasks
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
        {
            WebBrowserTask wbtask = new WebBrowserTask();
            wbtask.Url = "http://google.com";
            wbtask.Show();
         }
    }
}
```

Appreciate anything that you can suggest. I have no web browser control on the mainpage, could this be the issue? I don't want anything there, I just want the user to open the app and it immediately open the website... like a bookmark.

Sorry, this is my first project, so go easy on me.

Errors from the output are:

1>C:\Users\Dan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\HTC elevate\HTC elevate\MainPage.xaml.cs(25,16,25,18): error CS1519: Invalid token '+=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
1>C:\Users\Dan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\HTC elevate\HTC elevate\MainPage.xaml.cs(25,23,25,41): error CS1520: Method must have a return type
1>C:\Users\Dan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\HTC elevate\HTC elevate\MainPage.xaml.cs(25,57,25,58): error CS1001: Identifier expected
1>C:\Users\Dan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\HTC elevate\HTC elevate\MainPage.xaml.cs(26,9,26,10): error CS1519: Invalid token '{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
1>C:\Users\Dan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\HTC elevate\HTC elevate\MainPage.xaml.cs(28,24,28,25): error CS1519: Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
1>C:\Users\Dan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\HTC elevate\HTC elevate\MainPage.xaml.cs(29,24,29,25): error CS1519: Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
1>C:\Users\Dan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\HTC elevate\HTC elevate\MainPage.xaml.cs(32,1,32,2): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

Thanks

Comment: Hi, please tell us **what your errors are**.

Comment: updated with errors from the output. Thanks

Comment: You have signifcant syntax problems. You attempt to register MainPage_Loaded event but don't even have the method signature/prototype that will handle the event. Look up a tutorial on how to register events within a C# application. Your problem is the fact your syntax is just plain wrong. Your `{` after `Loaded += ...` is invalid.  I might be harsh in saying your code is **wrong** but your expected to do some research before asking a question and this didn't happen with this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're incorrectly declaring the `Loaded` handler - it should be in the body of a function. Alternatively, I would recommend using `OnNavigatedTo`:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowserTask wbtask = new WebBrowserTask();
            wbtask.Url = "http://google.com";
            wbtask.Show();
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        }
```

The reason for that is simple - it is guaranteed to be triggered only once for each page load.

Answer (score 1):

Move your code that assigns the loaded event handler INSIDE the MainPage constructor. It is currently inside the class declaration, which is what the compiler is complaining about. That is also not the way to declare an event handler. Use Visual Studio's Intellisense (invoked when you type +=) to help guide you.